# What am I missing in my code? Javascript and XML

Tags: javascript, xml, html

I am a beginner in XML, html and javascript.  I wrote some code to grab and concatenate all the title elements in html, but I can't display the output in the way that I want. Can someone take a look at my code and give me some tips on how to fix my code? Thank you in advance for your help.

Current: result: Cities I want to visit Tokyo, JapanSantorni, GreeceChicago, USA

I would want something that looks like:

- result:
- Cities I want to visit
- Tokyo, Japan
- Santorini, Greece
- Chicago, USA

Here is the XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<rss version="0.92">
  <channel>
      <title>Cities I Want to Visit</title>
      <link>http://pinterest.com/manicmonster/cities-i-want-to-visit</link>
      <Description>I love traveling!</Description>
      <item>
          <title>Tokyo, Japan</title>
          <link>http://www.gotokyo.org/en</link>
      </item>
      <item>
          <title>Santorini, Greece</title>
          <link>http://www.visitgreece.gr/en/greek_islands/santorini</link>
      </item>
      <item>
          <title>Chicago, USA</title>
          <link>http://www.cityofchicago.org/city/en.html</link>
      </item>
      <item>
          <title>Rome, Italy</title>
          <link>http://www.turismoroma.it/?lang=en</link>
      </item>
  </channel>
</rss>
```

Here is the html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
  <title>Practice</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">  
</head>
  <body>
    <div id="clickme" onclick="startAjax()">Click me</div>
    <script>
        function startAjax(){
          $("#clickme").text("Calling server");
          $.ajax({url:"test.xml",       
          success:callbackFunction, error:errorFunction});
        }

        function callbackFunction(data,info){
          var titles = $(data).find("title:first");
          var items = $(data).find("item title");

          if (titles && titles.length)
            $("#clickme").text("result: " + titles.text() + " " + items.text());
          else
            errorFunction(data, "No titles");
          }

        function errorFunction(data,info){
          $("#clickme").text("error occurred:"+info);
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function callbackFunction(data,info){
  var titles = $(data).find("title:first"),
      items = $(data).find("item").reverse(),
      items_idx = items.length,
      html= "";

  while (items_idx--){
      var txt = items[items_idx].find("title").text(),
          url = items[items_idx].find("link").text();

      html += "<li><a href='" + url + "'>" + txt + "</a></li>";
  }
  if (titles && titles.length)
    $("#clickme").text("result: " + titles.text() + " <ul>" + html + "</ul>");
  else
    errorFunction(data, "No titles");
}
```

Comment: Just my opinion here on the coding style - rather than decrementing the length variable like that, I'd use a traditional `for` loop with a regular index variable. This may work just fine, but you're reusing that variable as an index rather than what its name suggests, which may get confusing if you need that length again.

Comment: It would help if you explain the change rather than having to do a diff mentally

Answer (score 0):

```
var items = $(data).find("item title");
```

This line gets a collection of xml nodes. Later when your code executes this line:

```
items.text()
```

It takes the collection and returns the comma separated string of values. (e.g. Tokyo, JapanSantorini, GreeceChicago, USARome, Italy)

As [Malk](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17665054/1165635) implies, you need to use a loop to get each individual value and add them to a list. You can use that example, or use the jQuery `each` method on your collection

```
html = "";
items.each(function(index, value) { 
   html += "<li>" + value + "</li>";
});
```

Assuming, of course, you want a bulleted list. But the idea holds true that iterating through the collection seems closer to what you want.